# When findAll does not return ALL data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is very much an ember.js noob question but I can't find any article that talk about it. All tutorials that talk about getting data from the server talk about the findAll() command. I don't know a 3rd party api that will ever return all data.

If I want to use the youtube api it will return the first page of results but not all data. How do you deal with an api that returns paginated data? Or an api that is returning new data as videos are added to youtube in a feed of recent activity?

Answer (score 0):

There are some pagination mixins available for emberJS, one of them being:

https://gist.github.com/tchak/1559628

Written by one of the main emberJS contributors.